# get_the_date not working in custom single.php

Tags: wordpress, date

I have set up a custom single template for a specific category using the following:

```
// custom single template for specific category
function wpse_custom_category_single_template( $single_template ) {

        // global $post;

        // get all categories of current post
        $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
        $top_categories = array();

        // get top level categories
        foreach( $categories as $cat ) {
                if ( $cat->parent != 0 ) {
                        $top_categories[] = $cat->parent;
                } else {
                        $top_categories[] = $cat->term_id;
                }
        }

        // check if specific category exists in array
        if ( in_array( '7', $top_categories ) ) {
                if ( file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/single-custom.php' ) ) return get_template_directory() . '/single-custom.php';
        }

        return $single_template;

}

add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpse_custom_category_single_template' );
```

Within single-custom.php, I am using:

```
<?php echo get_the_date('F jS, Y', $post->ID); ?>
```

but it is pulling in the date from very first post in all of this category (ie. showing the same date on each single post). Within all other posts not using the custom single template, the date appears fine. Can anyone suggest where I am making the error.

EDIT to show single-custom.php

```
        <?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
     *
     * @package FoundationPress
     * @since FoundationPress 1.0.0
     */

    get_header(); ?>
    <?php
            if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
            yoast_breadcrumb('
            <p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>
            ');
            }
        ?>
    <header>
    <h1 class="hero-title">Customers <span>&amp;</span> Resources</h1>

    </header>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="main-grid">
            <main class="main-content-full-width single-news">
            <div class="news-bar">
                <h2>Case Studies</h2>

                <?php 
                    $args = array(
        'prev_text'          => '<span class="fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Previous Study',
        'next_text'          => 'Next Study <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </span>',
        'screen_reader_text' => 'News navigation',

        'excluded_terms'     => '6',
        'taxonomy' => 'category'
    );
    the_post_navigation($args); ?>

        </div>
        <div class="single-news-articles">
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header>

            <h3 class="entry-title"><?php wp_title(); ?></h3>

            <span class="news-date"><?php get_the_date('F jS, Y', $post->ID); ?></span>

    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
    <?php 
            the_content(); 

        ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( __( '(Edit)', 'foundationpress' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <?php
            wp_link_pages(
                array(
                    'before' => '<nav id="page-nav"><p>' . __( 'Pages:', 'foundationpress' ),
                    'after'  => '</p></nav>',
                )
            );
        ?>
        <?php $tag = get_the_tags(); if ( $tag ) { ?><p><?php the_tags(); ?></p><?php } ?>
    </footer>
</article>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-news">
    <?php 
                    $args = array(
        'prev_text'          => '<span class="fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Previous Study',
        'next_text'          => 'Next Study <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </span>',
        'screen_reader_text' => 'Case Study navigation'
    );
    the_post_navigation($args); ?>
    </div>
                </div>

                <?php endwhile;?>
            </main>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo do_shortcode("[consultant]"); ?>

    <?php get_footer();
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your `single-custom.php`?

Comment: @Xhynk I have edited above to show single-custom.php

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could just remove the `$post->ID` from `get_the_date()`:

```
echo get_the_date( 'F jS, Y' );
```

If that doesn't work, you could try using the function `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`:

```
echo get_the_date( 'F jS, Y', get_the_ID() );
```

Side note:

It also appears you have an extra `</div>` in your code, is that intentional? If not, I've cleaned it up a little bit to make it a bit easier to parse through:

```
<?php
    /**
    * The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
    *
    * @package FoundationPress
    * @since FoundationPress 1.0.0
    */

    get_header();

    if( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) )
        yoast_breadcrumb( '<p id="breadcrumbs">', '</p>' );
?>
<header>
    <h1 class="hero-title">Customers <span>&amp;</span> Resources</h1>
</header>
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="main-grid">
        <main class="main-content-full-width single-news">
            <div class="news-bar">
                <h2>Case Studies</h2>
                <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        'prev_text'          => '<span class="fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Previous Study',
                        'next_text'          => 'Next Study <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </span>',
                        'screen_reader_text' => 'News navigation',
                        'excluded_terms'     => '6',
                        'taxonomy'           => 'category'
                    );
                    the_post_navigation( $args );
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="single-news-articles">
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                        <header>
                            <h3 class="entry-title"><?php wp_title(); ?></h3>
                            <span class="news-date"><?php get_the_date( 'F jS, Y' ); ?></span>
                        </header>
                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <?php edit_post_link( __( '(Edit)', 'foundationpress' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                        </div>
                        <footer>
                            <?php
                                wp_link_pages(
                                    array(
                                        'before' => '<nav id="page-nav"><p>' . __( 'Pages:', 'foundationpress' ),
                                        'after'  => '</p></nav>',
                                    )
                                );

                                if( get_the_tags() )
                                      the_tags( '<p>', ', ', '</p>' );
                            ?>
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                    <div class="footer-news">
                        <?php
                            $args = array(
                                'prev_text'          => '<span class="fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Previous Study',
                                'next_text'          => 'Next Study <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"> </span>',
                                'screen_reader_text' => 'Case Study navigation'
                            );
                            the_post_navigation( $args );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    echo do_shortcode("[consultant]");
    get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code from `single-custom.php` it is hard to say for certain but it sounds like your `$post` variable does not contain the item that you are wanting the date for. Be sure that you are reassigning the global `$post` variable on each loop iteration. Something like this will do it placed inside your loop.

```
$your_query_object->the_post();
echo get_the_date('F jS, Y', $post->ID)
```